# Is "the technology" correct in this sentence or not and why?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

This was my statement:

> "You have to submit to **the** technology and instead of fighting against its functions try to adapt yourself ... "

Then somebody corrected a part of my sentence to " . . submit to technology".

I would like to know why "the" is not needed here?

I just followed my ears writing it that way.

Comment: We need more context - are you talking about technology in general or a specific technology?

Comment: Ok. There was a piece of news saying gov. filtered that website or social network. Then I put a comment, say " I'm afraid you have to submit to the technology"

Comment: Now, I understand something, in the above argument I can claim that my article "the" is correct, because I meant " the technology of social network", and on the other hand, it could infer technology in general, which in this case I conclude that it's not correct, am I right?

Comment: answers and comments on this website is slow.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear when you understand what you place the definite article there for.

If you are speaking about **technology** in general, any kind of technology, not some specific or defined technology, then you don't need the definite article **the**. On the other hand if you refer to some specific or defined technology, one that was mentioned ealier or one that is known from the context, then you should place the definite article there.